# CRM Analytics: Design Style Guide Application failed to install

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, crm-analytics

In `CRM Analytics`, in `Analytics Studio`, there is a `Template Gallery`:

[image]

If I select the `Design Style Guide` application and install, I get this error:

> Application failed

and

```
Result Log
Successfully created folder [Design Style Guide] with id [00l4J000001AiZsQAK]
Successfully created dataset [UX_Sample_Data_1].
Successfully created dataset [Fins_Sample_Data].
Successfully created dataset [static1].
Generation of resource type [xmd], label [UX_Sample_Data_1] failed. Maximum Rows Returned by XMD Query has been exceeded. Current value is 20000, and the limit is 19999
Generation of resource type [xmd], label [Fins_Sample_Data] failed. Maximum Rows Returned by XMD Query has been exceeded. Current value is 20000, and the limit is 19999
Generation of resource type [xmd], label [static1] failed. Maximum Rows Returned by XMD Query has been exceeded. Current value is 20000, and the limit is 19999
Creating application [Design Style Guide] failed.
```

This is a standard template, so I don't understand why it is failing.

Please could you advise?